# Organizing a database to store/fetch user events and dates

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, database-design

I'm looking for some help in order to build the database architecture that fits my needs:

Everyday my users (between 30 and 50 of them) will register events on my website.
They can register up to 100 events per day (each event has a specific id) and i need to store the date `dd/mm/yyyy` of the events they registered, so i can display their full history in the website while also allowing them to filter it by dates or show stats (like average number of events per day over the past week).

I've never done that kind of database and I'm not sure which way to go.
I was thinking automatically add a column in my database everyday, to organize the data by dates, but i read that this will needlessly overload my database overtime.

One alternative could be to store all the events of the same user in a single cell, and then parse the data with php when i do my queries.
I don't really know which way to go in order to be decently efficient.

Comment: *"i need to store the date dd/mm/yyyy of the events they registered"* - Why in *that* format? You should use MySQL's built-in date features that saves as `YYYY-MM-DD` instead by using `DATE` as its (column) type; it makes querying a lot easier too.

Comment: each event should have its own row. link it to a reference table for users

Answer (score -1):

I recommend you to create two tables:

Events Table: stores data about each event
Events Log Table: stores a log about changes made on each event

In the Log table, you could store log_id, event_id, created_date, updated_date, and log_data to store meaningful information about the log (something like comments in git commits).